# Запомнить данные введенные в форму api yandex карт

Tags: yandex-maps-api, form, localstorage

Пользователь открывает метку и вводит в поле input свои данные. Как сделать так, чтобы данные хранились в localstorage? То есть при перезагрузке сайта пользователь видел в этой форме свои введенные данные?
https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager/

это пример из песочницы API Яндекс Карт
https://jsfiddle.net/wzbh12dr/

```
ymaps.ready(init);

function init () {
var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
        center: [55.76, 37.64],
        zoom: 10
    }, {
        searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
    }),
    objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
        // Чтобы метки начали кластеризоваться, выставляем опцию.
        clusterize: true,
        // ObjectManager принимает те же опции, что и кластеризатор.
        gridSize: 32,
        clusterDisableClickZoom: true
    });

// Чтобы задать опции одиночным объектам и кластерам,
// обратимся к дочерним коллекциям ObjectManager.
objectManager.objects.options.set('preset', 'islands#greenDotIcon');
objectManager.clusters.options.set('preset', 'islands#greenClusterIcons');
myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);

$.ajax({
    url: "data.json"
}).done(function(data) {
    objectManager.add(data);
});

}
```

data.json

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
    {"type": "Feature", "id": 0, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.831903, 37.411961]}, "properties": {"balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>"}},
    {"type": "Feature", "id": 1, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.763338, 37.565466]}, "properties": {"balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>"}},
    {"type": "Feature", "id": 2, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.763338, 37.565466]}, "properties": {"balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>"}},
    {"type": "Feature", "id": 3, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.744522, 37.616378]}, "properties": {"balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>"}},
    {"type": "Feature", "id": 4, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.780898, 37.642889]}, "properties": {"balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>"}},
    {"type": "Feature", "id": 5, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.793559, 37.435983]}, "properties": {"balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>"}},
    {"type": "Feature", "id": 6, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.800584, 37.675638]}, "properties": {"balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>"}},
    {"type": "Feature", "id": 7, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.716733, 37.589988]}, "properties": {"balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>"}},
    {"type": "Feature", "id": 8, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.775724, 37.56084]}, "properties": {"balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>"}},
    {"type": "Feature", "id": 9, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.822144, 37.433781]}, "properties": {"balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>"}},
    {"type": "Feature", "id": 10, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.87417, 37.669838]}, "properties": {"balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>"}}

]
}
```

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Оптимальное добавление множества меток</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <!--
        Укажите свой API-ключ. Тестовый ключ НЕ БУДЕТ работать на других сайтах.
        Получить ключ можно в Кабинете разработчика: https://developer.tech.yandex.ru/keys/
    -->
    <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru-RU&amp;apikey=<ваш API-ключ>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://yandex.st/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="object_manager.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
        html, body, #map {
            width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;
        }
        a {
            color: #04b; /* Цвет ссылки */
            text-decoration: none; /* Убираем подчеркивание у ссылок */
        }
        a:visited {
            color: #04b; /* Цвет посещённой ссылки */
        }
        a:hover {
            color: #f50000; /* Цвет ссылки при наведении на нее курсора мыши */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Для начала вам следует проверять наличие объекта **localstorage** и если он там есть, считывать его оттуда. Весь ли JSON там хранить или только вносимые в поля данные - решать вам.

Объект с элементами вам нужно будет закидывать в localstorage через **JSON.stringify()**, а считывая парсить через **JSON.parse()**

```
localStorage.setItem ("object", JSON.stringify(data));
data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem ("object"));
```

Определять, какой элемент JSON вам следует править, вы можете получая id метки при открытии балуна:

```
myMap.geoObjects.events.add('balloonopen', function (e) {
  var objectId = e.get('objectId');
})
```